# Susy span columns not filling grid

Tags: css, grid, sass, susy-compass

I am working with susy on my personal website, and I am running into a bizzarre issue where items are not actually filling all the way to the end of the last column they are supposed to span. I have turned the susy grid background on and put it up on my test server so that anyone who wants to can check it out [here](http://rchipman.scripts.mit.edu/ryanchipman_test/projects/).

The left margin seems to be getting set correctly, but the width seems to get set just a little too short. The odd part about it is that there is a certain degree of consistency to it. For example, if I have the nav bar span two more columns as in the screenshot below, the nav bar and the main panel fall short by exactly the same amount, despite the fact that they are spanning different number of columns.

[image]

Below is some relevant HTML and Sass, but I really cannot tell what the issue is. I have tried all sorts of changes, but nothing seems to fix it.

```
<body>
<div class="page">
  <header>
    <a href="/"><div class="title">R<span class="title-kern">y</span>an Chipman</div></a>
    <nav>
      <a href="/about"><div class="nav-tab" id="nav-left"><p>About Me</p></div></a>
      <a href="/projects"><div class="nav-tab" id="nav-mid-left"><p>Projects</p></div></a>
      <a href="/interests"><div class="nav-tab" id="nav-mid-right"><p>Interests</p></div></a>
      <a href="/contact"><div class="nav-tab" id="nav-right"><p>Contact</p></div></a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div class="sidebar">
  </div>
  <%= yield %> <!-- main content panel here -->
  <footer class="footer">
  </footer>
</div>
```

```
.page {
    @include container($total-columns);
    @include susy-grid-background;
    background-color: $light-gray;
    padding-bottom: 2.5em;
    header {
        .title {
            @include span-columns(8, 16);
            @include push(4);
            font-size: $headline-font-size;
            clear: both;
            margin-bottom: .25em;
        }
        nav {
            @include span-columns(8, 16);
            @include push(4);
            background-color: $white;
            height: $nav-height;
            clear: both;
            .nav-tab {
                font-size: $nav-tab-font-size;
                height: $nav-height;
                @include with-grid-settings(4,25%,0%,0%) {
                    @include span-columns(1, 4);
                }
                &#nav-left {
                    background-color: $blue;
                }
                &#nav-mid-left {
                    background-color: $green;
                }
                &#nav-mid-right {
                    background-color: $orange;
                }
                &#nav-right {
                    background-color: $red;
                }
                &:hover {
                    height: $nav-hover-height;
                    @include opacity(.75);
                }
                p {
                    padding-top: 12%;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    #main {
        @include span-columns(12,16);
        @include push(2);
        @include content-box;
        h1, h2, h3 {
            clear: both;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you re-size your browser, the background image will jump and occasionally line up. This is consistent because it is not a problem with your column spans, but with browser handling of background images. As the [docs note](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-grid-background), the grid image is not reliable for exact measurements, for this exact reason.

It all depends on the math being precise, so the browser doesn't have to do any rounding. Browsers do a terrible job with sub-pixel rounding on background images, and I've never seen any reliable workarounds.

Comment: Makes sense -- are you using a mac by any chance? There seems to be an issue (both on this site and on sarahsullivan.com) where the nav tabs are not filling the full length of their container in safari, leaving a little white strip to their right. I had originally thought that these were related, but apparently not. Do you have any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: They might be related. Your elements can suffer from sub-pixel rounding as well, but usually not to the same extent as the background. There's nothing you can do about single-pixel errors — those are just a part of fluid design. But if you are seeing larger gaps, those are caused my multiple rounding errors stacking up, and there are various things you can do about that. See the [isolation](http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-helper-isolation) features in Susy, for example.